# Ошибка в массиве

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где здесь ошибка:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `startpoke` (img,name_poke,life,atk,def,exp,type) VALUES('$row['img']','$row['name_poke']','$row['life']','$row['atk']','$row['def']','$row['exp']','$row['type']') ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Мне выбивает такую ошибку:

> `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\xampp\htdocs\style\register.php on line 50`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас в values одинарная кавычка стоит перед названием переменной и она же закрывается перед названием ключа массива. Т.е. должно быть не так:

```
'$row['name_poke']'
```

А так:

```
'".$row['name_poke']."'
```

И так с каждой переменной в values